# What is best practice to monitor storm cluster with some UI tool like Cloudera Manager?

Tags: user-interface, alert, monitor, apache-storm

This time, we build a storm cluster and don't have a tool like cloudera manager to monitor the status of cluster except the storm ui, and send alert notice when the cluster is in bad status.

Comment: Did u find any solution? I am in exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please write linux scripts with some basic storm commands and zookeeper commands to ensure the health of your cluster.

Comment: sorry, can you illustrate more , can you write an example for this ?